# How to avoid Velocity template rendering in browser

Tags: java, servlets, velocity

I used Velocity template and my class extends to VelocityViewServlet.
Everything is working fine but this servlet is rendering output to browser which i do not want. How can we just print the template in console.?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when saying "just print the template in console" ? Do you mean you are going to print it on your admin console panel for CMS editors or in browser console or maybe in server console?

Anyway,seems like you somehow use Velocity processor for this output, maybe there is some filter or even code in your servlet or something else for processing velocity files, what's you are going to achieve is quite easy you just need to skip this phase of velocity processing.

Comment: Hi Maksym, I am using template as email template.